# Flex-basis with percentage support for IE11?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with flexbox and ie10/11.
I wanted to use min-width / max-width values but that didn't work in IE11.
I found out about flex-basis which I used with a percentage value.
It works as expected in Chrome but not in IE11.

I tried adding flex-direction row and column but it also didn't work.

```css
/* List */

.c-collist {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*width: -webkit-fill-available;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Listitem */

.c-collist>li {
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: 45%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h4>Features</h4>
<ul class="c-collist t-name">
  <li>
    <img src="/pics/icon/e-5w92w-05-grww-000.svg" width="100" height="100" alt="Schalten" />
    <div class="c-flextext">
      <h5>Schalten</h5>
      <p>Ihr Smartphone wird genauso zur Schalt&shy;zentrale wie der Browser Ihres PCs. Je nach Modell schaltet das Web-IO in klassischer 24V Automatisierungs&shy;technik, mit potential&shy;freien Kontakten oder direkt 230V.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="/pics/icon/mqtt.svg" width="64" height="64" alt="IoT-Gateway" />
    <div class="c-flextext">
      <h5>MQTT und REST</h5>
      <p>Durch die Unterstützung von MQTT und REST ist das Web-IO 4.0 ideal vorbereitet für IoT-Lösungen und Industrie 4.0.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="/pics/icon/e-5w92w-08-grww-000.svg" width="100" height="100" alt="Melden" />
    <div class="c-flextext">
      <h5>Alarmierung</h5>
      <p>Ein potentialfreier Kontakt oder Grenzwert&shy;schalter reicht aus, damit das Web-IO im Ernstfall per E-Mail die zuständigen Mitarbeiter informiert. Weitere Alarmierungs&shy;möglichkeiten sind SNMP-Trap, TCP-Meldung, MQTT-Publish und mehr.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> Here is what I get with Chrome:

[image: Works as expected]

> And that's IE11

[image: Doesnt work as expected]

It works in IE11 when I use a pixel value of for example 250px.
But I have a media query that sets the width to 100% in mobile.
This also doesn't work and I really don't like to set a definite pixel value for mobile.

Comment: Where is flex-basis support for percent? I do not see it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)

Comment: if you scroll down under values: "<'width'>
An absolute <length>, a <percentage> of the parent flex container's main size property, or the keyword auto. Negative values are invalid. Defaults to auto."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be safe with IE11, you should stick to the very basics. 
This should work just fine:

```css
/* List */

.c-collist {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}


/* List item */

.c-collist li {
  width: 45%;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .c-collist li {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 520px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h4>Features</h4>
<ul class="c-collist t-name">
  <li>
    <img src="/pics/icon/e-5w92w-05-grww-000.svg" width="100" height="100" alt="Schalten" />
    <div class="c-flextext">
      <h5>Schalten</h5>
      <p>Ihr Smartphone wird genauso zur Schalt&shy;zentrale wie der Browser Ihres PCs. Je nach Modell schaltet das Web-IO in klassischer 24V Automatisierungs&shy;technik, mit potential&shy;freien Kontakten oder direkt 230V.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="/pics/icon/mqtt.svg" width="64" height="64" alt="IoT-Gateway" />
    <div class="c-flextext">
      <h5>MQTT und REST</h5>
      <p>Durch die Unterstützung von MQTT und REST ist das Web-IO 4.0 ideal vorbereitet für IoT-Lösungen und Industrie 4.0.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="/pics/icon/e-5w92w-08-grww-000.svg" width="100" height="100" alt="Melden" />
    <div class="c-flextext">
      <h5>Alarmierung</h5>
      <p>Ein potentialfreier Kontakt oder Grenzwert&shy;schalter reicht aus, damit das Web-IO im Ernstfall per E-Mail die zuständigen Mitarbeiter informiert. Weitere Alarmierungs&shy;möglichkeiten sind SNMP-Trap, TCP-Meldung, MQTT-Publish und mehr.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: without the minimum width the stuff shrinks dramatically before reaching mobile sizes

Comment: I would recommend to adjust your media query so that the li already takes `100%` at `768px` or shortly after. Maybe also adding a `max-width` to the li and a `margin: 0 auto` and it should look alright ?
I edited my answer so you can have a look.

Comment: thank you very much i also tried that out already i just need to ask chief if it's okay when i add another media query at 800px.
Jesus i still hope someone finds a better solution than us.

Comment: my instructor said it was okay to add another media query. However flex-grow works in IE10/11 so if i can make it behave like css-grid without javascript im gonna use that.
Problem with flex-grow is that the lone item will go full width of the container, instead of going max-width from 1 element of the above.